# making prefill date input in UI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, vmware-clarity

Hi I am new to vmware clarity UI, My problem I am using datetime-local I want to pre populate the current date and time in the datetime-local filed I am trying to do it using ngModel with following format 2017-06-13T13:00, its pre-populating on the UI but the time is not showing proper, **its behind 5hours IST** Please let me know where I am going wrong, Thanks in advance

html component

```
 <clr-input-container>
    <label>Start Time</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" clrInput [(ngModel)]="start_time" name="start_time" style="width:100%" required />
    <!-- <clr-control-helper>Please choose Incident Start Date&Time in DD/MM/YYYY Hr:M:-AM/PM</clr-control-helper> -->
    <clr-control-error>This field is required!</clr-control-error>
 </clr-input-container>
```

ts file

```
start_time =  new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 16);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Clarity, but rather how some HTML elements work.

The issue is that you are creating a new date that is based on UTC, and then dropping the timezone (the substr removes the Z). The `datetime-local` input assumes that it is in the local time zone. So you'll have to build the date in the local time zone and then it will display properly. You will have to construct the time manually (or use a library like MomentJS) because there is no JavaScript Date method that gives you the `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM` type format.

`datetime-local` is not supported by all major browsers, so I would caution against using it.